# JList not displaying Object[] in GUI

Tags: java, jlist

I'm running a local server that is listening to a particular port.

In the Client side app, I'm running a GUI that will display a List of News (Object created by me with a title and a body)

I send as a param an ArrayList and add it to my JList (ListNewsTitle)

```
public class GUI {

private Socket socket;
private Client client;
private JFrame Frame;
private JTextField TextSearch;
private JButton BtnSearch;
private JTextArea TextNewsBody;
private JList<News> ListNewsTitle;
private ArrayList<News> ListNews = new ArrayList<News>();

public GUI(Client client) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this.client = client;
    buildGUI();
}

private void buildGUI() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Frame = new JFrame();
    TextSearch = new JTextField();
    BtnSearch = new JButton("Search");
    TextNewsBody = new JTextArea();
    ListNewsTitle = new JList<News>();
    setFrame();
    setFields();
}



 //This method is called in the Client class.
        public void go(Socket socket, ArrayList<News> listNews) {
                this.socket = socket;
                this.ListNews = listNews;
                new ButtonAction(this);
                News[] news = new News[listNews.size()];
                listNews.toArray(news);
                System.out.println(news.length + " is the lenght of news");//displays the correct number.
            ListNewsTitle = new JList<News>(news);
            Frame.pack();
            Frame.setVisible(true);
        }
```

The JList is displayed in the GUI but for some reason it apears empty.
Since JList uses the method toString() I changed it aswell.

```
public News(String title, String body ) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return title;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `ListNewsTitle` a variable name or an object type? Where are you getting `ListNewsTitle` from? That part isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks. I would suggest following a naming rule. Normally variable names do not start with an upper case character.  In general, variable names are Pascal Case and classes are Camel Case. Constants are all uppercase.  See [this document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
ListNewsTitle = new JList<News>(news);
```

You're creating a separate object entirely with the new data, the existing list stays as it is (and is no longer referenced by that variable.) With `ListNewsTitle.setListData(news);`, you're modifying the *existing* list.

The distinction seems minor, but is very important. When you replace the list, any other objects that had a reference to the existing list won't get their list updated (as their list is a separate object to the one you've just created.) When you set the content of the *existing* list, then any objects that have a reference to that same existing object will see its updated state.

In this case, the objects that have a reference to the existing object include the GUI components - hence you need to modify the existing list, not create a new one, for the changes to show.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the solution I was looking for.